# Is it possible to upload files using ssh connection?

Tags: php, ssh

im using a ssh connection to a server, and i would like to know if there ia a command to upload files, like the put on the sftp connection.

```
include('Net/SSH2.php');
include('Crypt/RSA.php');

$key = new Crypt_RSA();

$key->loadKey(file_get_contents('/pathtokey.pem'));


$ssh = new Net_SSH2('ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com');
if (!$ssh->login('user', $key)) {
exit('Login Failed');
}
```

thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send files via SSH using SCP

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-scp-send.php

Comment: maybe i wasnt clear, i know theres a way using the ssh2_connect, i want to know if theres a command using the net_ssh2

Comment: Looking at the documentation i couldnt find anything helpful :(

Comment: net_sftp is a child class of net_ssh2 and has a put method:
http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/documentation/net.html#net_sftp_put