# How to upload image from server to other server using php

Tags: php, php-curl

I tried the below code for uploading the image from one server to another server using php. But am unable to get the image uploaded in the destination server. Please let me know if I did any wrong in my code.

Code used in `form.php`, which is on my source server:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" encoding='multipart/form-data' method='post' action="form.php">
    <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" value="choose">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
   </form>
   <?
   if ( isset($_FILES['uploadedfile']) ) {
   $filename  = $_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'];
   $handle    = fopen($filename, "r");
   $data      = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
   $POST_DATA = array(
  'file' => base64_encode($data)
   );
   $curl = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.kanchikart.in/img/handle.php');
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $POST_DATA);
   $response = curl_exec($curl);
   curl_close ($curl);
   echo "<h2>File Uploaded</h2>";
   }
  ?>
```

and in my `handler.php` which is on my destination server:

```
<?php
  $encoded_file = $_POST['file'];
  $decoded_file = base64_decode($encoded_file);
  /* Now you can copy the uploaded file to your server. */
  file_put_contents('<span style="color: red;">subins</span>', $decoded_file);
  ?>
```

After trying with the above code I am not getting the image to be stored in my destination server.

Comment: Any error message? I see you do nothing with `$response`. You should check it, for starters. Then you should look at the logs in your destination server.

Comment: No error message, in the source server am getting the message as "File uploaded" but in the destination server no error message showing. Can you please tell me how to check for logs in my destination server.

Comment: Is there any other alternate solution like, can we move the file to destination server from source server itself, i.e without writing any coding in destination server.Is this possible?

Comment: Depends on how your web server and how it is configured, but supposing apache with default configuration on ubuntu IIRC you should find it under `/var/log/apache/error_log`

Comment: And yes, it is possible (and sometimes even desirable) to skip http entirely. `sftp` or `scp` are what you may be looking for.

Comment: Thank you, any reference url where can I get the same, please...

Comment: Now that I look at your destination code what is that `'<span style="color: red;">subins</span>'` doing in your call to `file_put_contens`?

Comment: Anyway, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10823269/is-it-possible-to-upload-files-using-ssh-connection).

Comment: It will create a folder and put the content in it.

Comment: Why not use the ```CURLFile``` class to upload files and get the target files on the target server via ```$_FILES```? https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.curlfile.php

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with `https` endpoints you need additional options set in the curl request - specifically a valid cacert... you can download your own copy of `cacert.pem` from [curl.haxx.se](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html)

Test the response or use the `info` ( http_code ) to determine success or failure. The following appeared to work for me and yielded a 200 response code ~ check to see if there is a new file

```
<?php

    if ( isset($_FILES['uploadedfile']) ) {

        $filename  = $_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'];
        $handle    = fopen($filename, "r");
        $data      = fread($handle, filesize($filename));

        $POST_DATA = array(
            'file' => base64_encode( $data )
        );
        $cacert='c:/wwwroot/cacert.pem';
        $url='https://www.kanchikart.in/img/handle.php';

        $curl = curl_init();
        if( parse_url( $url,PHP_URL_SCHEME )=='https' ){
            curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true );
            curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2 );
            curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $cacert );
        }

        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $POST_DATA);

        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        $info = (object)curl_getinfo( $curl );
        curl_close ($curl);


        echo ( $info->http_code==200 ) ? "<h2>File Uploaded</h2>" : "<h2>Bogus</h2>";

    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>cURL - Server to Server....</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" encoding='multipart/form-data' method='post'>
            <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" value="choose">
            <input type="submit" value="Upload">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes have downloaded and altered the code as "$cacert='http://sampledemos.online/testandroid/cacert.pem';
        $url='https://www.kanchikart.in/img/handle.php';", but still am not getting image in my destination server.

Comment: download the cacert and use a local copy ( whilst you are supposed to be able to use a url based cacert I had issues before ) - the endpoint url should have the `https://` etc in rather than what you show above in the comment. Have you checked the server to confirm if I managed to upload anything - the script suggests it was OK